# PHP Main page script with GET Won't work

Tags: php

I've made a simple index.php script for my homepage, however, it won't work.

```
<?php
$Query = $_GET['p']
if (strtolower($Query) == "about") {
include("About.php")
die()
}
if (strtolower($Query) == "") {
include("Home.php")
die()
}
if ($Query) {
include("Home.php")
die()
}
?>
```

It's my first time coding in php so i don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Missing semicolons.

Comment: @MarcB: A bit too harsh on a first-time question poster..

Comment: Also harsh on a first-time PHP user.

Answer (score 0):

First you need simicolons. Second, why die? Why not do something like.

```
<?php
$Query = $_GET['p']
if (strtolower($Query) == "about") {
    include("About.php");
} else {
    include("Home.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: If the current page is also being `include`d, `die` will stop all further processing. Not the best way to do things, but it's potentially useful.